# Is it possible to dynamically enable/disable an item in the OSX services menu?

Tags: macos, cocoa, service, menu

I have an application that registers a service in the OSX services menu, which works fine.

The application can only perform the service operation if the user has run the application and entered a password (the application provides encryption).

Is there a way that I can disable or even only make the service menu shown when these conditions are met? I can't seem to find anything that suggests it is possible.

Thanks

Comment: Why not prompt the user for the password in case the password has not been entered yet?

Comment: I was thinking that. However if I show a login window and wait for the password to be entered. The application that the service was initiated from hangs and eventually times out.

Comment: Did you find any mechanism to enable/disable option based on some condition controlled in app?